# How to add "where" clause to calculating maximum value in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.2.0 and Scala 2.11. I want to calculate `rank` as `sold` divided by maximum sold value within the same `type` (i.e. the same as actual row's value). But I do not know how to consider `type` when calculating `max`.

This is my current code. It calculates `sold` as the difference between the maximum and minimum stock for the given period of time. The value `sold` means how many products were sold in this period of time.

```
val sales = df.select($"product_pk",$"type",$"stock").groupBy($"type",$"product_pk").agg((max($"stock")-min($"stock")) as "sold")
val ranks = sales.withColumn("rank",$"sold"/max($"sold"))
```

Comment: you should go with window function

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: Could you please provide more details about this?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan: `.withColumn("rank", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"type").???` But where do I put the calculation of `rank`?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example if you want ppl to be able to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what you can do, if I understood your question correctly

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("type")
val ranks = sales.withColumn("rank",$"sold"/(max($"sold").over(windowSpec)))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: So, in this case `rank` will be calculated for each row, but only within the same `type`, right?

Comment: yes definitely. If you are confused you can test it with your sample data. :)